# .htaccess Rewrite Rule for 5-letters

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

this should be a fairly simple one for you.

I want to redirect all entries that use a combination of 5 numbers / letters to a subsite.

The user would enter
http://www.foo.com/ABC12 and it should rewrite to
http://www.foo.com/foo/ABC12

As the RewriteRule I put in :

```
RewriteRule /([a-zA-Z0-9]{5}) /foo/$i [L]
```

I am pretty sure about this first part. But not sure how to fully implement the rule.

Does anybody have an idea?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: instead of `$i` should be `$1` ... otherwise it should work. If you want to actually redirect you need `[R,L]`

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to do... You want to redirect the user to `/foo/...`? _Why_?

Answer (score 0):

The correct implementation of what you suggest would be this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?([a-z0-9]{5})/?$ /foo/$1 [NC,R=301]
```

That rule will work in the http servers host configuration and likewise in dynamic configuration files (`.htaccess` style files).

Note: I do not really understand the motivation behind this, I only offer the implementation of what you ask. Note however, that for this to make sense at least the http server has to be able to fulfill a request to `/foo/...`, so not to throw an error for example for a non existing resource...

In case a resource `/foo/...` can *not* be fulfilled and you only want the client to be visually redirected, whilst on the server the original URI is served, then you need to add an internal reversion rule:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?([a-z0-9]{5})/?$ /foo/$1 [NC,R=301] 
RewriteRule ^/?foo/([a-z0-9]{5})/?$ /$1 [NC,END]
```

If that results in an internal server error (http status 500, you will find more detailed information in your http servers error log file...), chances are that you are operating a very old version of the apache http server and need to replace the `END` flag with the `L` flag. That should work too for the given situation.

---

A general hint: you should always prefer to place such rules inside the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those files are notoriously error prone, hard to debug and they really slow down the server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have control over the host configuration (read: really cheap hosting service providers) or if you have an application that relies on writing its own rewrite rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).